# Should a friend operator in a class with enum parameters be found by Koenig lookup?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

Consider the following code:

```
enum A : unsigned { a = 1, b = 2, c = 4 };

class B
{
  friend constexpr A operator|(A a1, A a2)
  { return A(unsigned(a1) | unsigned(a2)); }
};

template <A a>
class C
{
};

int main()
{
  C<a|c> c;
}
```

When compiled with g++ (4.8.1, -std=c++1), I get the following error:

```
test.C: In function ‘int main()’:
test.C:16:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘A’ [-fpermissive]
       C<a|c> c;
```

Which tells me that the operator is not being found.  However, if the code is changed to:

```
enum A : unsigned { a = 1, b = 2, c = 4 };

constexpr A operator|(A a1, A a2)
{ return A(unsigned(a1) | unsigned(a2)); }

template <A a>
class C
{
};

int main()
{
  C<a|c> c;
}
```

Then it compiles and runs fine.  Is the error in the first case a compiler error, or I do misunderstand something?  I would like to use the method of Boost.Operators to easily define operators by declaring a class with base classes from templates which define the operators, but this result precludes that in this case.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: (pure) Argument-dependent lookup (aka Koenig lookup) is dependent on the argument expressions, not on the context of the call. Would you expect `auto x = a|c;` to find the operator declared inside `B`?

Comment: You might want to explain what you want to do for those of us unfamiliar with Boost.Operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to solve it (other than jogojapan already mentioned), is to simply declare the friend function outside the scope.

```
enum A : unsigned { a = 1, b = 2, c = 4 };

//declaration
constexpr A operator|(A a1, A a2);


class B
{
  //definition inside, ok.
  friend constexpr A operator|(A a1, A a2)
  { return A(unsigned(a1) | unsigned(a2)); }
};

template <A a>
class C
{
};

int main()
{
  C<a|c> c;
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. The problem is not with the *lexical scope*, but with the fact that a friend function defined inside the class is not *visible* outside of the class unless/until a declaration for that function is also provided at namespace level. +1

Comment: You're correct, but this way, there is not really a benefit any more to having the definitions of these functions inside a class.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to have something like: `template <typename T> class BitwiseEnum { friend constexpr T operator|(T, T) { ... }; friend constexpr T operator&(T) { ...} friend constexpr T operator~(T) { ...} };`  which could then be used to "define" this set of operators for any Enum later with out rewriting the definitions constantly.  Something like `Enum A { ... }; class AWrapper : BitwiseEnum<A> {};`  Unfortunately, `class AWrapper : BitwiseEnum<AWrapper::A> { Enum A { ... }; }; typedef AWrapper::A A;` won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I took another approach, and here's code which solves my problem:

```
template <typename UNSIGNED>
struct BitwiseEnum
{
  enum class Enum : UNSIGNED
  {
  };

  constexpr static Enum value(unsigned bit)
  {
    return Enum(UNSIGNED(1) << bit);
  }

  friend constexpr Enum operator|(Enum a, Enum b)
  {
    return Enum(UNSIGNED(a)|UNSIGNED(b));
  }

  friend constexpr Enum operator&(Enum a, Enum b)
  {
    return Enum(UNSIGNED(a)&UNSIGNED(b));
  }

  friend constexpr Enum operator~(Enum a)
  {
    return Enum(~UNSIGNED(a));
  }
};

class MyMask : public BitwiseEnum<unsigned long>
{
};

typedef MyMask::Enum Mask;

constexpr static Mask a = MyMask::value(0);
constexpr static Mask b = MyMask::value(1);
constexpr static Mask c = MyMask::value(2);
constexpr static Mask d = MyMask::value(3);


template <Mask A>
class B
{
};

int main()
{
  B<a|b> test;
}
```

Now, when I defined a lot of enums like "MyMask", it can be done fairly simply, without much more code than a simply defined enum would have.  And it behaves as one would "expect" from a bit field enum, can be used in strongly type checked template arguments, etc.